# What is the difference between last_over_time() and instance vector?

Tags: prometheus, promql

`last_over_time(metric{}[1h])` returns the latest (recent) sample of samples' set in 1 hour (now - 1 hour)
`metric{}` instant vector returns the latest (recent) sample of samples' set.

These samples would be equal, am I wrong?

When to use the `last_over_time` and just instant vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus stops returning time series if the distance between the latest sample and the requested timestamp exceeds 5 minutes by default. It may also stop returning series with more recent samples if there are staleness markers exist after these samples - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) for details.

So, basically, `metric_name` query is somewhat equivalent to `last_over_time(metric_name[5m])`. These queries may return different results if the requested series contain stale markers.